# Handling a JSON String After API GET Request on iOS

Tags: ios, json, api, get

I am using a free weather API for an app.  All I really need from the output is forecasted Low Temp, Forecasted High Temp, and conditions.  In my app I set up the NSURLConnection and everything, and it works fine.  My code is:

```
-(IBAction) weatherView {




    NSString *bringitalltogether = @"http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=79201&format=json&key=22gxkzqxwjvzxp44e3wvdp2c";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:bringitalltogether]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];


    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
    [connection release];

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"RESPONSE%@", response);
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]])
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
        //If you need the response, you can use it here
        int code = [httpResponse statusCode];
        NSLog(@"%i", code);
        if (code == 200){

        }

        else
        {
            UIAlertView *oops = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:@"The weatherman is having difficulties getting you the forecast.  Please check your network settings and try again later." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [oops show];
            [oops release];
        }

    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    NSMutableDictionary *allResults = [NSJSONSerialization
                                       JSONObjectWithData:data
                                       options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                       error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Data was received%@", allResults.description);


}
```

Everything seems to work great, I just don't know where to turn to from here to take from the JSON string output and weed out only what I actually need.

The output that I receive is:

```
{
    data =     {
        "current_condition" =         (
                        {
                cloudcover = 0;
                humidity = 19;
                "observation_time" = "05:57 PM";
                precipMM = "0.0";
                pressure = 1005;
                "temp_C" = 22;
                "temp_F" = 72;
                visibility = 16;
                weatherCode = 113;
                weatherDesc =                 (
                                        {
                        value = Sunny;
                    }
                );
                weatherIconUrl =                 (
                                        {
                        value = "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png";
                    }
                );
                winddir16Point = WNW;
                winddirDegree = 300;
                windspeedKmph = 35;
                windspeedMiles = 22;
            }
        );
        request =         (
                        {
                query = 79201;
                type = Zipcode;
            }
        );
        weather =         (
                        {
                date = "2014-02-28";
                precipMM = "0.0";
                tempMaxC = 25;
                tempMaxF = 77;
                tempMinC = 2;
                tempMinF = 35;
                weatherCode = 113;
                weatherDesc =                 (
                                        {
                        value = Sunny;
                    }
                );
                weatherIconUrl =                 (
                                        {
                        value = "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png";
                    }
                );
                winddir16Point = NW;
                winddirDegree = 307;
                winddirection = NW;
                windspeedKmph = 33;
                windspeedMiles = 20;
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: If "Everything seems to work great" for what reasons you have posted your code?

Comment: What is the question? How to parse JSON?

Comment: You know `allResults` is a dictionary so have you tried requesting the value for a key from it?

Comment: For the first two people who responded, if you read my question, after the section you quoted I also said: , I just don't know where to turn to from here to take from the JSON string output and weed out only what I actually need.  So sorry for not specifically stating in question form, How do I take this JSON String and pull out ONLY what I need.  I thought the way I worded it would have been fine enough.  I am not for sure how to request the value for a key from the dictionary.  This is my first time working with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here your code

```
// get data
NSDictionary *getData = [allResults objectForKey:@"data"];
NSArray *currentConditions = [getData objectForKey:@"current_condition"];
NSArray *weathers = [getData objectForKey:@"weather"];

NSDictionary *currentCondition = [currentConditions objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"current temp = %@", [currentCondition objectForKey:@"temp_C"]);

NSDictionary *weather = [weathers objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"hight temp = %@", [weather objectForKey:@"tempMaxC"]);
NSLog(@"low temp = %@", [weather objectForKey:@"tempMinC"]);
```